# Get most recent salary for the Employee

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Employee table which has Empl_id,Hourly rate and effective date.
I want to get the Hourly rate  of the employee for a give month if it exists if not give me the most recent Hourly rate  for that employee.

```
select EMPL_ID, HRLY_AMT
from Employee   a
where exists (select 1
              from Employee b
              where b.EMPL_ID = a.EMPL_ID and
                    b.EFFECT_DT between '2019-10-01' and '2019-10-31'
             )
group by EMPL_ID
```

Data Sample

```
       Empl ID     HOUR_AMT   EFFECT_DT
         1            10       2017-07-01
         1            20       2018-10-01
         1            40       2019-10-01
         2            40       2017-06-01
         2            45       2018-09-01
         2             60      2019-09-01
```

Now If I pass Month = 07 & Year = 2017

It should show

```
        Empl ID     HOUR_AMT   EFFECT_DT
         1            10       2017-07-01
         2            40       2017-12-01
```

Now If I pass Month = 11 & Year = 2019

```
            Empl ID     HOUR_AMT   EFFECT_DT
             1            40       2019-10-01
             2             60      2019-09-01
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: And explain the correlation between hourly rate and monthly salary

Answer (score 0):

You could use exists, but I prefer INNER JOINs.  The inner join will remove all results except the one that falls immediately after your @GivenMonth.

```
SELECT EMPL_ID, HRLY_AMT
FROM Employee AS a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT EMPL_ID, MIN(EFFECT_DT) AS EFFECT_DT
    FROM Employee
    WHERE EFFECT_DT >= @GivenMonth
    GROUP BY EMPL_ID
    ) AS r ON r.EMPL_ID = a.EMPL_ID AND r.EFFECT_DT = a.EFFECT_DT
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Following:

1. For Recent Hourly rate of the employee

```
select EMPL_ID, HRLY_AMT
from  (select ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY EMPL_ID ORDER BY EFFECT_DT AS DESC) RecentRN
              from Employee b
              where b.EMPL_ID = a.EMPL_ID and
                    b.EFFECT_DT between '2019-10-01' and '2019-10-31'
       )
where RecentRN = 1
```

2. For Highest Hourly rate of the employee

```
select EMPL_ID, HRLY_AMT
from  (select ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY EMPL_ID ORDER BY HRLY_AMT AS DESC) HighRate
              from Employee b
              where b.EMPL_ID = a.EMPL_ID and
                    b.EFFECT_DT between '2019-10-01' and '2019-10-31'
       )
where HighRate = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have entry of two values "month and Year" your query should be

```
SELECT  Empl_ID ,
        HOUR_AMT ,
        EFFECT_DT
FROM    ( 
        SELECT    Empl_ID ,
                    HOUR_AMT ,
                    EFFECT_DT ,
                    A.CurDiff,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY A.Empl_ID ORDER BY ABS(A.CurDiff) ) Row_Id
          FROM      ( SELECT    Empl_ID ,
                                HOUR_AMT ,
                                EFFECT_DT ,
                                DATEDIFF(DAY, CONVERT(DATE, @Year + '/' + @Month + '/01'), EFFECT_DT) CurDiff
                      FROM      @tbl
                    ) A
        ) Final
WHERE   Final.Row_Id = 1
```

To view the demo for the output of this query **[Click Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=48158d7baf278bf8afbfd0af7a53115f)**